# How to grayed out the button in Xpage

Tags: xpages

Please help me out in the below case:

When we clicked on the button in the current window (which has Cancel and OK button in the title bar). then it should display the small pop up with Two buttons. (Apply defaults and cancel button)

When we clicked on the Apply defaults in the small pop up, then the pop up should be closed and then display the previous window with disable(grayed out) the cancel button in the title bar.

Please let me know how to grayed out the cancel button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subbu,

Make your "Cancel" button in the title bar a dijit.form.Button. When the user clicks the "Apply defaults" button in the popup, you can then call a clientside script to disable it:

```
dijit.byId("#{id:yourCancelsButtonId}").setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do it client side you should be able to accomplish the same thing server side like:

```
var buttonComp = getComponent("IdOfButtonToDisable");
buttonComp.setDisabled(true);
```

I'm not sure if you'll have to do a partial refresh to make it show up but that should work.