# What's the best way to prevent multiple submission in XPages?

Tags: xpages

What's is the best way to prevent multiple submission when I'm using XPages?

For "classic web" solution is below.
How to Block Multiple Submissions of the Same Document from the Web
http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089865

Using jQuery, the solution is below.
http://www.norio.be/blog/2008/09/using-jquery-prevent-multiple-form-submissions

But I don't know the way in Xapges. How to prevent it in XPages or Dojo?

Comment: Also have a look at this question and the answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258858/how-to-grayed-out-the-button-in-xpage

Answer (score 1):

It is best **not** to apply such client-side techniques, because combined with an unreliable internet connection the user may find that the submission fails but be unable to retry.

A much more robust solution is to deduplicate on the server side, which can be done in a variety of ways; these are some that come to mind:

1. Define the semantics of your form contents so that it doesn't matter if you receive two requests (e.g. if it is updating a record, then a second update just changes nothing).
2. If you have seen the exact same submission before (compare all the relevant fields), ignore it.
3. Generate a serial number when you send the form to the client. Don't accept submissions that have a serial number you've seen before — or do something useful; for example, if it is a blog posting or comment form, then a second submission should be treated as an *edit* to the post created by the first submission.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.
You are right. We should Check it on Server-side.
My question was bad.

I'd like to know easy way to prevent multiple submission on client-side.
Because Xpages is seemed to prevent making conflict document even then there are multipele submissions. So I think I don't need strict way.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a submit by using XSP.addQuerySubmitListener and return false. This is not the easiest function to get working. So I suggest you take a look at the function in the book 'Xpages Portable Command Guide' or try my project multiple file uploader on OpenNTF. Download the project source code [here](http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects%5Cpmt.nsf&documentId=D5639B5FFB2823F8862578AF00705169&action=openDocument).